# How to compare two dates in a program?

Tags: c++, comparison, console-application

So, there are two dates and I have to check if `date1` is further away than `date2`. What is the best way to do that?

```
int date1_day = 21, date1_month = 1, date1_year = 1990;
int date2_day = 19, date2_month = 5, date2_year = 1989;

if(???)
{
   // date1 is further away
}
```

I'm struggling with this one for hours.

Comment: Multiply and add to get appropriate numbers to compare.

Comment: Have you tried using your favourite search engine first?

Comment: I strongly recommend using a proper datetime-processing library instead of rolling-your-own. Unfortunately C++'s standard library does not have a `date` type, but Boost (which is a kind-of unofficial standard library) does. There are many gotchas with date-processing (such as timezones and daylight savings, UTC, leap-years, political changes, different calendar systems, the Gregorian v. Julian change, etc) which is why it's always best to use a datetime library.

Comment: Well Veronica was ok but Betty was better.

Comment: @Dai, This is just a simple comparison of  integers! you don't need a library or in fact convert those to a date!

Comment: @AaA You do. What happens if you get the input tuple `d: 30d, m: 2, y: 2015`? As there is no 30th of February any simplistic comparison would fail to detect invalid input data.

Comment: @dai, in this case you don't, there is no mention of a valid date in question or data validity. what he need to compare is two date represented by `integers`, which obviously `1990-02-35` is further than `1990-02-28` although the date is not valid

Answer (score 8):

Try this without using any logical operators:

```
int date1 =  date1_day + date1_month*100 + date1_year*10000;
int date2 =  date2_day + date2_month*100 + date2_year*10000;  

if(date1 > date2)  
     printf("date1 is further away than date2\n");
```

Comment: That's a great trick, which allows easy manipulation in aaaammdd ! Thanks !  However, as 25 bits are required to store such numbers, be carefull not to use it for some older (embedded) systems having 16 bits int  ;-)

Comment: @Christophe; Yes, of course :)

Answer (score 6):

It's not rocket surgery:

```
if ( date1_year > date2_year ||
    (date1_year == date2_year && date1_month > date2_month) ||
    (date1_year == date2_year && date1_month == date2_month && date1_day > date2_day))
{
    // date1 is further away
}
```

With a little more thought I'm sure you can come up with a simpler method.

Comment: "Rocket surgery" has just become my favorite mixed metaphor.

Comment: ["rocket appliances"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TR3QHoqfhX8)

Answer (score 2):

COmpared to the 5 logical operators and 6 compares of Paul, R,  here a version with 4 logical operators and 5 compares):

```
if(date1_year>date2_year || 
     (date1_year==date2_year && (date1_month>date2_month 
               || (date1_month==date2_month && date1_day>date2_day))))
```

Comment: Premature optimisation is the root of all evil. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) from [`<tuple>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) to lexicographically compare multiple variables.

```
if (std::tie(date1_year, date1_month, date1_day) >
    std::tie(date2_year, date2_month, date2_day))
{
    // date1 is further away
}
```

Comment: +1: good answer - I've never use `std::tie` before - this looks useful!